# byte[] length from LargeInteger.bitLength()

Tags: java, arrays, bit, content-length, jscience

I'm trying to convert a [`LargeInteger`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html) into a `byte[]` of unknown length using [`bitLength()`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#bitLength%28%29) with

```
static byte[] encodeint(LargeInteger y) {
    //byte[] in = y.toByteArray();
    byte[] in = new byte[(int)Math.ceil((double)y.bitLength() / 8.0)];
    y.toByteArray(in, 0);
    //
    byte[] out = new byte[in.length];
    for (int i=0;i<in.length;i++) {
        out[i] = in[in.length-1-i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

but the executor returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

which points to `y.toByteArray(in, 0);`.

How can the length of `in` be properly set?

(The commented code is leftover from converted `BigInteger` code.)

Comment: BTW, it's faster, more compact, and likely more robust to compute the number of bytes as `(y.bitLength() + 7) / 8`.

Comment: @HotLicks Hmm, it didn't like that.  Are you sure it's correct?  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What didn't it like??

Comment: @HotLicks It gives the same error.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc for toByteArray tells you

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - if bytes.length < (bitLength() >> 3) + 1

Thus in should be `>= (bitLength() >> 3) + 1`

What you have done is nearly the same except you have not added the 1.

So `(int)Math.ceil((double)y.bitLength() / 8.0) -1`

but easier to use the documented version
`y.(bitLength() >> 3) + 1`

Comment: Thank you Mark!  I was thinking it was due to the remainder.  I think for this code (ed25519), it should be as precise as possible, but I don't know.  Would you mind adding a snippet to add `1` if there's a remainder?

Comment: @Gracchus = the documented version is a precise as possible as if any less you will get the exception